# PHP Call a page from other server having commands

Tags: php, powershell

I have a PHP Test server i need to call a script or page of server B that has ipconfig command.
When this page to be called from hosing server it should show the IP of server B

Comment: Hi Chris. Can you elaborate on your question? As it stands, there's not a lot of context that will help other users provide an answer that may be useful to you. SO has guidelines to help [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions.

Comment: @Darragh Enright I have a PHP TEST Sevrer S1 which has an index.php page.
Now there is one machine which is my local pc or else.
When call index.php page it should show the ipconfig of my local machine.

I want to execute some cmd from php to my local machine.

Comment: @DarraghEnright

Comment: You propably want [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6). Look at the examples, try to implement something and come back when you have *specific* problems with your code.